# How do I reuse recorded scripts in JMeter in newer builds?

Tags: android, jmeter

I am using `Jmeter 5.3.` and I recorded a script with a proxy set up on an `Android P` handset.  I was able to record activities on a `Native Android app`.  However, this was just for one build.  Tomorrow if I checkout builds from `Android Studio` to my device, will the same script work?  Or is there a technique wherein I script/record once and run on subsequent builds.  Or is there some other tool/framework that I should look at?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter script doesn't run on the "device" and isn't connected to Android OS by any means.

Given you were able to record your application network activity it seems that your application uses at least [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol to speak with the [backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_and_back_end), see [Performance Testing for Native Mobile Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/view-webcast-performance-testing-native-mobile-apps) webcast for more comprehensive information if needed.

JMeter **replays** the recorded requests absolutely independently. So given there are no changes in [API contract](https://medium.com/theagilemanager/development-what-is-an-api-contract-683ced58e06f) - you should be able to re-use the same script.

Also be aware that with JMeter you can only load test the backend, Android application performance per se can be assessed using i.e. [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)